# Is it possible to run debootstrap within a fakeroot environment?

Tags: debian, debootstrap, fakeroot

I have a script that prepares an installation image by running `debootstrap`, does some modifications on the files and then copies the files to a disk image backed up by a file.

This works under `root`, but I wanted to be able to run the script without `root` privileges, as it really shouldn't need any privileged resources. I thought that I'd just run the whole script using `fakeroot`, but `debootstrap` fails with

```
W: Failure trying to run: chroot /tmp/tmp..... mount -t proc proc /proc
```

Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 5):

In general, **yes**, it is possible to run `debootstrap` as a non-root user by way of `fakeroot`, but there are more details to it than that.

The immediate problem you seem to be having is trying to use `chroot` as a non-root user; you need to use [`fakechroot`](https://github.com/dex4er/fakechroot/wiki) instead, in addition to `fakeroot`. For example:

```
fakechroot fakeroot debootstrap sid /tmp/sid
```

Later problems you may run in to include creating loopback mounts or creating disk image partition tables as a non-root user.

Instead of working through all these details one by one, you may find it easier to use a debootstrap variant like [polystrap](https://github.com/josch/polystrap), which also handles cross-compilation (eg, generate an armhf image from x86-64) if you end up wanting that some day.

Comment: The problem is that `debootstrap` itself is calling `chroot`, and I couldn't find a way how to tell it it needs to use `fakechroot`.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Did you try fakerootng instead of fakeroot? They operate differently, so sometimes one works when the other one doesn't. I don't know if fakerootng makes chroot work.

Comment: @PetrPudlák: the [fakechroot man page](https://github.com/dex4er/fakechroot/blob/master/man/fakechroot.pod) gives an example invocation as `fakechroot fakeroot debootstrap sid /tmp/sid`

Comment: @PetrPudlák: --variant=fakechroot should do that. Beyond that: unshare/lxc-userns-exec are a 'better' way to do this in combination with multistrap (i.e. the idea behind polystrap, which was rolled into brickstrap).

Answer (score 3):

debootstrap has an option `--variant=fakechroot` to do exactly what you are trying to do (see [doc](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/debootstrap/debootstrap.8.en.html#variant=minbase_buildd_fakechroot)).

Comment: [`--variant=fakechroot` docs](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/debootstrap/debootstrap.8.en.html#variant=minbase_buildd_fakechroot)

Answer (score 1):

The [chroot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html) syscall requires root privilege, or more exactly & technically the 
`CAP_SYS_CHROOT` capability (see [capabilities(7))](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

Hence you can't use just `fakeroot` on it (you also need [`fakechroot`](https://wiki.debian.org/fakechroot) etc).